# PHP Namespace and global variable issue within classes

Tags: php, namespaces, global-variables

I am stuck with this confusion where I don't understand why my global $error under my HelperClass() returns empty, where I could verify that $class->error is indeed filled up with data earlier on.

Is there some sort of issues with namespace in this case that I am not aware about? Please give me some pointers.

Here are some of the codes that are relevant.

Under Main file

```
namespace Core;
$class = new ControllerClass();
$error = $class->error;
// verified that $error prints correctly here
include ViewFile.php;
```

Under ViewFile.php

```
$helper = new HelperClass();
// __autoload function took care of the include
```

Under HelperClass:

```
namespace Core\Skeleton;

class HelperClass {
public function __construct() {
global $error;
// $error != $class->error as defined earlier    
// $error is empty here
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using an autoloader or include your classes from within another helper function, then the `$error` variable was never declared in the 'global' scope. It ended up in some local, and got disposed.

Declare it shared right before you assign it a value.

```
namespace Core;
$class = new ControllerClass();
global $error;
$error = $class->error;
```

Also while there is nothing wrong with shared variables per se. The name `$error` seems slightly too generic. Maybe you can up with a less ambigious or more structured exchange variable. `$GLOBALS["/var/log"]["controller_error"]` or something arrayish.