# Laravel blade global variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem in global variables in laravel. I know about view composer and my question is not related to that subject.
How can I do such a simple thing in laravel view (*.blade.php | *.php) template engine?
for example this is a sample code from one of my views (*.blade.php | *.php):

```
<?php
   function myFunc() {
     global $myvar;
     if ( ! $myvar ) {
       $myvar = 'my var is empty';
     }
     dd( $myvar );
   }

  $myvar = 'my var value';
  myFunc();
```

At the end of the execution it shows up 'my var is empty' and not 'my var value'.
Anybody knows why this happens?

Comment: first ,why you need to run `php` in your blade? I had used it in some of my views without problem `<? php ?>`

Comment: @Sachith I just want to simplify the problem, I have to use this `php` codes in my project the main problem is **global** keyword it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found my answer, it has scope issue. because laravel uses class and methods to retrieve **view** so based on this page inforamtion: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#98811

so we can write the code like this:

```
<?php
   function myFunc() {
     global $myvar;
     if ( ! $myvar ) {
       $myvar = 'my var is empty';
     }
     dd( $myvar );
   }

  global $myvar; // This line is the key
  $myvar = 'my var value';
  myFunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use the `Config` facade. You can create a new config file and set, in your case, global variables statically. But the best feature of this facade, are the `get()` and `set()` methods, which allow you to define these variables dynamically. See: [Set Global variables in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923763/set-global-variables-in-laravel-5)

In your case:

```
<?php
function myFunc() {
 $myvar = Config::get('vars.myvar');
 if ( ! $myvar ) {
   $myvar = 'my var is empty';
 }
 dd( $myvar );
}

Config::set('vars.myvar');
myFunc();
```

Make sure you import the `Config` facade by using `use` on the top of your file.

Comment: It looks good, but it's not proper for my situation. I just want to solve that problem, because I have to work with functions which are created before.

Comment: But this works in the same way as using 'global', right? I dont really understand why using the Config way isnt what you are looking for? Please enlighten us! By the way, you shouldnt use this inside Blade, its bad practise.

Comment: I have to integrate wordpress and laravel for my company, and I want to use visual composer for some part of my website. and the only issue that I have, is this.

Comment: Okay, thats clear. The problem in your case is probably because Laravel uses multiple namespaces within your autoloader. The following link describes more of its possible solution, although I am not sure if this fits your situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374947/php-namespace-and-global-variable-issue-within-classes

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you can pass values from your included sub-blade to your main blade by declaring the variable you wish to pass values with as global in both the main and sub view. The key is declaring the passing variable as global on both ends (i.e., in both the main and included blade).

For instance:

**INCLUDED SUB-BLADE**

```
<? global $monetary_total; ?> <!-- somewhere up top of your sub-blade declare your variable as global scope  -->

@foreach ($monetary_assets_joint as $monetary_asset)

.... your code that cycles through rows and pulls a value...

<td>{{$monetary_asset->monetary_asset_value}} </td> <!-- somewhere you'll display the pulled values -->

... rest of your view code and markup ....

<?php $monetary_total += $monetary_asset->monetary_asset_value; //summing up pulled row value into passing variable ?>  

@endforeach
```

**MAIN BLADE:**

```
<? global $monetary_total; ?> <!-- somewhere up top of your blade declare your variable as global scope  -->

...

@include('partials.sub_blade') <!--  somewhere you include your sub-blade -->

...

{{$monetary_total}}  <!-- display summed total from included sub-bade's rows -->
```

Hope this helps.