# How can I track Laravel framework entry point

Tags: php, laravel

for some a reason I need to track entry point of laravel framework,how can I do that, is there any way to do that, I need to debug also how can laravel load service provider of package step by step is there any way or something like so, I ask just if can tell me how?
and what I mean by track?
I mean to display stack trace when laravel run,  to see variables loaded into memory.

Comment: your question is too broad but if you are seeking for debugging help and some of session value, stack info etc. then you might want to take a look at this package for your development.  https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar. or Using dd() to print out global variable. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40052410/laravel-blade-global-variable?rq=1

Comment: I'd suggest using xdebug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entry point is `./public/index.php`. For debugging people usually use [xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) but I never really needed it. I usually just `dd($something)`. If you have laravel 6 you have `ddd()` helper that dumps the variable but also shows you the stack trace and other useful info. You can `ddd()` directly in the `./vendor` in the provider if you want. Put any variables you want to see in the `ddd`. If you don't have laravel 6 then you can throw an exception to see the trace or `dd()` whatever you want to see. There are other ways of course but this was always enough for me.

Comment: yes, ```dd``` it's working inside vendor dir, I don't think it will work inside vendor